# Xpath, php and how to skip specific node (and it's children)

Tags: php, html, dom, xpath

I've just started tooling around with XPath recently.
Currently I'm just parsing some pages line by line and taking the relevant text.

What I'd like to do is exclude a `div` at the top **and it's child elements**.

Basically I'm looking at this :

```
<html>
  <head> Foo </head>
  <body>

    <div id='header'>
      <ul id='menu'> <li> Bar </li> <li> FooBar </li> <li> BarFoo </li> </ul>
    </div>

    <table> <tr> <td>data</td><td>data</td> </tr> </table>

    <div>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
      <p>dolor sit amet</p>
    </div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Except much more content.

Currently I loop through every node with :

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.test.com/test.htm');

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$nodes = $xpath->query('/html/body//*');

foreach($nodes as $node) {
  echo $node->nodeValue;
}
```

**I want to ignore the entire header node.**

*Is there a simple way to just **do** that?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This would work:

```
/html/body//*[not(ancestor-or-self::div[@id="header"])]
```

The XPath selects all nodes below the body element unless they are an ancestor of a DIV with the id attribute value of "header" or that div itself.

Check http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0704_xpath.html for an XPath tutorial.